# How to change a table from MyISAM to InnoDB?

Tags: mariadb

```
ALTER TABLE `file_exist`
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

results in `Error Code: 1005. Can't create table` schema`.`file_exist `(errno: 140 "Wrong create options")`

how to change a table to InnoDB?

Comment: you should read https://mariadb.com/kb/en/converting-tables-from-myisam-to-innodb/ extensivly

Comment: @nbk thanks. I just read that doc and don't see any particular obstacles. The pk and only key is on an unsigned int (that's my default) no additional indexes, no obscure data types. Could current_timestamp be a problem?

Comment: There is something in the current table options that are incompatible with innodb. Look at `show create table` and the contents after the final `)`. Something there might be MyISAM only.

Comment: @theking2 make something like https://dbfiddle.uk/-IPPPGtE

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the ALTER TABLE statement converting required, in my case, setting the ROW_FORMAT option to DYNAMIC. Doing so allowed the simple table to convert in the [blink of an eye](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt13265982/?ref_=ext_shr).